# Grub boots from kernels that I removed

Tags: fedora, kernel, dnf

I'm running Fedora 26, `rpm -qa kernel` outputs `kernel-4.13.5-200.fc26.x86_64`. And that's the one I want.

[image]

I had 3 kernels showing in grub, that one, and 2 newer ones, Wifi wasn't working when booting from the other two so I excluded kernel updates from dnf, and I removed the newer kernels `sudo dnf remove kernel-4.x`.

All went smoothly, however when I restart, I still can see them in grub and I can boot from them and the wifi won't work if I pick them.

Here I am booting from the newest kernel that I removed.

[image]

Here's my grub

[image]

What went wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set your default entry without removing the newest kernel through `grub2-set-default` command. In your case without updating grub2 use:

```
grub2-set-default 2
```

After grub update you should have tow kernel on your grub 2 configuration file the command should be (the first kernel is `0` the second one is `1`):

```
grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
grub2-set-default 1
```

The command :

```
# awk -F\' '$1=="menuentry " {print i++ " : " $2}' /etc/grub2.cfg
```

will print the exact order of the existing kernel on the `grub.cfg` file.

Fedora project :  [Setting default entry](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/GRUB_2#Setting_default_entry)

Comment: didn't work but I'm accepting because fedora the kernel and it's now the top one https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/402614/does-fedora-use-dnf-when-updating-through-shutdown-dialog so as long as i don't update it, it will still be on top

Answer (score 2):

Look in `/var/lib/initramfs-tools/` if the newer kernel-versions are present.

Erase them, also in /boot relevant entries, like vmlinuz initrid and System.map. But be carefull, that you don't delete the false one!!

As root or with sudo `update-grub`

Comment: Your answer is wrong . Reason: Question is tagged "fedora" but Fedora does not have an "update-grub" command. This is only found on Ubuntu and some other deb-based Linux distros. And /var/lib/initramfs-tools/ is also only found on deb based distros.