# Does Fedora use dnf when updating through shutdown dialog?

Tags: fedora

I'm on fedora 26 gnome. I did `exclude=kernel*` in `dnf.conf` because kernel updates are breaking my wifi. I wanted to stay on `kernel-4.13.5-200.fc26.x86_64` Yesterday, I installed updates through the [dialog](https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel/2015/08/pngcktHzmmNXZ.png) and went to sleep.

I wake up today and all I have is

```
kernel-4.13.9-200.fc26.x86_64
kernel-4.13.10-200.fc26.x86_64
```

Wifi is broken in 13.9 but luckily working in 13.10. I'm considering leaving fedora because what just happened is unethical, if wifi wasn't working in 13.10 I'd be spending hours trying to fix it and I didn't want it in the first place.

How does fedora update when shutting down?

Comment: Can you add the `cat /etc/default/grub` and the `awk` output from the previous post?

Comment: @GAD3R to this post or to the previous post

Comment: in the previous post should be better , to get a working answer

Comment: Yes, Fedora 26 uses `dnf`.  How is it unethical?

Comment: @fpmurphy1 I excluded kernel updates in dnf, but when I shutdown it was updated,  kernel updates break my pc. That's unethical

Comment: After you modified `dnf.conf` did you do a ``dnf clear all`?

Comment: @fpmurphy1 I don't remember, I modified it a while ago, and the pc has been restarted and everyday since and updated numerous times before the incidence, wouldn't that have the same effect as `dnf clear all`?

Comment: Gnome Software Center and the pre-boot updater use PackageKit to install software and updates. It does not use the same cache and settings as `dnf`

Comment: @Mioriin I thought so, is it possible to exclude kernel from it?

Comment: There's a way to turn off PackageKit's auto-updater daemon, but I can't remember how. There are a couple of threads about it on ask.fedoraproject.org Try looking about in there.